# Compare the habits between move and smart pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, move

In C++11/14, an object can be transfered by `move` or smark pointer.

**(1)** This is an example for `move`:

```
class MoveClass {
private:
    int *tab_;
    int alloc_;
    void Reset() {
        tab_ = nullptr;
        alloc_ = 0;
    }
    void Release() {
        if (tab_) delete[] tab_;
        tab_ = nullptr;
        alloc_ = 0;
    }

public:
    MoveClass() : tab_(nullptr), alloc_(0) {}
    ~MoveClass() {
        Release();
    }
    MoveClass(MoveClass && other) : tab_( other.tab_ ), alloc_( other.alloc_ ) {
        other.Reset();
    }
    MoveClass & operator=(MoveClass && other) {
        if (this == &other) return *this;
        std::swap(tab_, other.tab_);
        std::swap(alloc_, other.alloc_);
        return *this;
    }
    void DoSomething() { /*...*/ }
};
```

When we use this movable `MoveClass`, we can write code like this :

```
int main() {
    MoveClass a;
    a.DoSomething();  // now a has some memory resource
    MoveClass b = std::move(a);  // move a to b
    return 0;
}
```

Always write move-constructor/move-operator= is boring, use shared_ptr/unique_ptr some times have the same effect, just like java, reference/pointer everywhere.

**(2)** Here is the example:

```
class NoMoveClass {
private:
    int *tab_;
    int alloc_;
    void Release() {
        if (tab_) delete[] tab_;
        tab_ = nullptr;
        alloc_ = 0;
    }

public:
    NoMoveClass() : tab_(nullptr), alloc_(0) {}
    ~NoMoveClass() {
        Release();
    }
    MoveClass(MoveClass && other) = delete;
    MoveClass & operator=(MoveClass && other) = delete;
    void DoSomething() { /*...*/ }
};
```

We can use it like this:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<NoMoveClass> a(new NoMoveClass());
    a->DoSomething();
    std::shared_ptr<NoMoveClass> b = a; // also move a to b by copy pointer.
    return 0;
}
```

Is it a good habit to always use the 2nd one?

Why many libraries, STL use the 1st one, not the 1st one ?

Comment: In your first example MoveClass lives on the stack, in the second, on the heap. Allocating everything on the heap and using smart pointers can introduce a significant overhead. Not to mention that the semantics are different.

Comment: @KinanAlSarmini  will 'tab_' and 'alloc_' on heap cost so much ? are there any performance benchmark data ?

Comment: @zhaochenyou an extra indirection will cost something to be sure, but the point is the semantics are just different, these two techniques are not interchangeable

Comment: @Ap31 yes, sometimes, I just want to write less code

Comment: C++ lets you do just about whatever you want. If you find that this suits your needs, and the performance cost is insignificant for *your* application, then go for it.

Comment: @zhaochenyou _"Will (allocation) on heap cost so much?"_ Let's compare: 1) stack allocation requires changing stack pointer according to the size requested. 2) Heap allocation requires a) check data structures that record heap allocation for where to allocate b) update said structures to ensure future allocations don't overlap c) reverse the record-keeping on de-allocation d) ensure that concurrent alloc/de-alloc requests from multiple threads don't conflict. _Yes all this is abstracted behind whatever allocator implementation is used, but the work still has to be done._ So what do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Always write move-constructor/move-operator= is boring

You **almost never** need to write your own move constructor/assignment, because (as you mentioned) C++ supplies you with a number of basic resource managers - smart pointers, containers, smart locks etc.

By relying on those **in your class** you enable default move operations and that results in minimal code size as well as proper semantics:

```
class MoveClass {
private:
    std::vector<int> data;
public:
    void DoSomething() { /*...*/ }
};
```

Now you can use your class as in **(1)** or as a member in other classes, you can be sure that it has move semantics and you did it in the minimal possible amount of code.

The point is one usually only needs to implement move operations for the most low-level classes which are probably covered already by STL, or if some weird specific behavior is needed - both cases should be really rare and not result in "Always writing move-constructor/move-operator=".

Also notice that while approach **(1)** is unnecessarily verbose, **(2)** is just unacceptable - you have a resource managing class that doesn't do its job and as a result you have to wrap it in smart pointers everywhere in your code, making it harder to understand and eventually resulting in even more code than **(1)**